# Pass React Native Component to children and render it in the same position

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

In the Parent Component I have some `<View/>` positioned in a relative way.

In a children Component I need to replicate the rendering of some `<View/>` in the exact coordinates but this time in an absolute way (in order to put them upside the first ones).

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

it's a tutorial-like screen, i need to add a View with a transparent background and a button that is present on the parent but it must be of the same size and position from screen top-left corner, independently from the device and screen resolution it must be on the same position.

Comment: Can you share an image of what you want exactly?

Comment: it's a tutorial-like screen, i need to add a View with a transparent background and a button that is present on the parent but it must be of the same size and position from screen top-left corner, independently from the device and screen resolution it must be on the same position.